# Connecting Python to mysql using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I need to connect Python with `mysql` using `pymysql`, but instead of selecting a particular database I want to choose it from a list of dbs available in that server/host. Is this possible?

I have tried to make a GUI, and need to know if I should add adatabase field (which clients will never know about). Should I add any fields? How should I make it connect to the server itself without database mentioned in it?

[This is my GUI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMx2k.png)

---

**CODE:**

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
label=Label(root,text="this is server connection table".upper(),font=("Arial",9,"bold")).place(x=45,y=3)

HOST=Label(root,text="HOST name:".upper(),font=("Arial",9,"bold")).place(x=20,y=40)
TAB1=Entry(root,bd=1).place(x=105,y=42,width=120)

USER=Label(root,text="USERNAME:".upper(),font=("Arial",9,"bold")).place(x=20,y=60)
TAB2=Entry(root,bd=1).place(x=105,y=62,width=120)

PASSWORD=Label(root,text="PASSWORD:".upper(),font=("Arial",9,"bold")).place(x=20,y=80)
TAB3=Entry(root,bd=1).place(x=105,y=82,width=120)

Submit=Button(text="submit".upper(),bd=1).place(x=150,y=150)
exit=Button(text="EXIT".upper(),bd=1,command=root.quit).place(x=220,y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's not supported to connect without specifying the db you could try, after the user presses the submit, to connect to the information_schema  db. And with this connection established, try to select all db names on the host. (For example by using MySQLs "SHOW DATABASES") you could feed this data as a list into a drop down menu (like in: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-create-dropdown-menu-in-tkinter/)